# Image appears distorted until CSS height rule is reapplied

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I've got a div containing an image as shown below. When I open the popup which contains the div, the image appears stretched:

[image]

However, if I uncheck and check the `max-height` property

[image]

the image now renders correctly with the exact same CSS.

[image]

```css
.kmaweV {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.lpgaMv {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://minimalistbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/EASY-1-Pot-Massaman-Curry-Basic-ingredients-BIG-flavor-lots-of-protein-options-for-vegan-vegetarian-and-meat-eaters-plantbased-glutenfree-curry-massaman-recipe-minimalistbaker-34.jpg" class="sc-fzoxKX lpgaMv"></div>
```

Comment: Funny bug. Your code snippet is running just fine. Any chance there is another css rule having a side effect on this?

Comment: just wondering how you expect anyone to help with this question?  The code runs fine.

Comment: I also just noticed that in your snippet you have a closing ```</div>``` before your image tag. Is that supposed to be like that?

Comment: @kenput3r no its not, updated that, thanks for spotting

Comment: @DCR I know it does, that's why I'm having issues debugging - could this be an issue with the image not loading fully before the css is applied? I'm running this on Safari on a Mac

Comment: Confirmed snippet is running fine on Chrome (Windows; 83.0.4103.116)

Comment: @esqew this works for me on Chrome too, it seems to only occur on Safari

Comment: remove the max-width attribute

Comment: @Alk couldn't recreate the bug with the snippet on safari

Comment: I've also noticed that in Chrome the image seems to be cached as when the popup is opened, no network request is made and the image appears instantly. On Safari, a network request is made every time to fetch it, and the image takes a fraction of a second to load as well, its not instant.